# How to know which ad was clicked and send that data to a singles page

Tags: python, flask, e-commerce

I'm practicing with a flask website that is sort of a mock classifieds website. On a browse page, I am displaying all results for whatever a user searches for. How can I track which ad was clicked by the user so I can redirect them to a 'singles' page where it will show in greater detail the item they clicked on...?

My first instinct was to use sessions, but I just couldn't quite figure out the logic. I am rendering the data dynamically, where in the HTML template, data contains all the query results:

```
<ul class="list">

                    {% for row in data %}

                            <a href="/iLike/">
                                <li>
                                    <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/logo.png') }}"
                                         title="" alt=""/>
                                    <section class="list-left">

                                        <h5 class="title">{{ row[1] }}</h5>

                                        <p class="catpath">
                                            <Strong>Condition</strong>: {{ row[3] }}</p>
                                        <p class="catpath"><Strong>details</strong>: {{ row[2] }}</p>
                                        <p class="catpath"><strong>Looking for</strong>: {{ row[5] }}</p>
                                    </section>

                                    <section class="list-right">
                                        <span class="date">{{ transType }}</span>

                                    </section>
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                </li>
                            </a>
```

Comment: add some argument to link - ie `href="/iLike/?ad_number=1"` or `href="/iLike/1"` (but it needs argument in route).

Comment: Wow, I feel like this question was so simple now. maybe i should take a break. put it as answer adn i'll accept. thanks a lot @furas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some argument to link - ie `href="/iLike/?ad_number=1"` or `href="/iLike/1"` (second version needs argument in route/function)